# Kali Linux not connecting to network via lan

Tags: linux, internet, ethernet, lan

I tried all solutions available on the internet but none work.

I changed(added) interfaces to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inst dhcp
```

I changed NetworkManager.conf to

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

I restarted the service also tried rebooting but it is not connecting to the router.

Just showing this:

[image: enter image `description here]

On ifconfig I get:

[image]

Comment: have you tried to check if the card is supported? What happens if you type `ip eth0`?

Comment: @OleAldric it shows Object eth0 is unknow

Comment: @OleAldric it was working with live boot